# EF Core Navigation to a Model not found. Add navigation to entity type before configuring it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two models

```
public  class PickTaskListAssignment
    {
        [Key]
        public System.Guid PickTaskListAssignmentID { get; set; }
        public Guid PickTaskListAssignmentStatusID { get; set; }
        
        public virtual PickTaskListAssignmentStatus PickTaskListAssignmentStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class PickTaskListAssignmentStatus
    {
       

        [Key]
        public Guid PickTaskListAssignmentStatusID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PickTaskListAssignment> PickTaskListAssignment { get; set; }
    }
```

Both have been added on the db context.

```
public virtual DbSet<PickTaskListAssignmentStatus> PickTaskListAssignmentStatus { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<PickTaskListAssignment> PickTaskListAssignment { get; set; }
```

But everytime I type in `dotnet ef migrations add picklist`

I encounter this error

> Navigation '.Models.PickPack.PickTaskListAssignmentStatus (Dictionary<string, object>).PickTaskListAssignment' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try renaming property `PickTaskListAssignment` of `PickTaskListAssignmentStatus` & make it plural `PickTaskListAssignments` because it is a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment said, for automatic navigation configuration, naming has to match.

When in you do not want to depend on the automatically configured relation, you can also explicitly define the relation in the Database Context.
For example, in the `OnModelCreating` you can specify the following:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<PickTaskListAssignment>(entity =>
    {
          
        entity.HasOne(d => d.PickTaskListAssignmentStatus)
            .WithMany(p => p.PickTaskListAssignment)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PickTaskListAssignmentStatusID);
     });
```

For more reference, see [EF Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Comment: Will definitely try to actually set the configuration upon building the migrations. Up to this moment, I usually just let it as it is. Thanks!